# Meteor check whether document already exists in collection or not?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am beginner in meteor. I have a form having username and password as input fields and a submit button in the end. 
I have correctly collected data from both fields into two variables. Now what I want is to verify whether any matching document exists in my MongoDB collection or not? My below code is not working. How to do it? Please help. Here is my code.

```js
Template.form.events({
  'submit.login':function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var user = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[0].value;;
    var pass = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[1].value;

    var usernamee = (Collection.Login.find({username: user},{password: pass})).count();

    if(usernamee>0) {
      alert("found");
    } else {
      alert("not found");
    }

    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you have `autopublish` package working or do you publish this collection yourself? Show the code, please.

Comment: Collections = {};

Collections.Login = new Mongo.Collection("login");

Comment: I have made this collection.

Comment: In both server and client files, right? How do you publish documents to client?

Comment: I do not need to publish documents right now. But if I have to, I would make template.helper in which Collection.find() method would be called.

Comment: Right now I just want to check whether username and password exists in my collection or not?

Comment: Your collection is on the server. On the client there is an empty collection, until you publish those documents. The code you've shown is the _client_ code.

Comment: Btw, your search query should be `{ username: user, password: pass }`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your `.find()` is incorrect:

```
var usernamee = (Collection.Login.find({username: user},{password: pass})).count();
```

shoud be:

```
var usernamee = (Collection.Login.find({username: user, password: pass})).count();
```

Assuming that you're publishing that collection to the client either with autopublish or an explicit publication.

*However:*

**You are giving even non-logged in users access to the usernames and cleartext passwords of all other users!**

Meteor includes the *accounts* package that takes care of user management for you. You don't need to reinvent the wheel. You want to take advantage of the security work that's already been done for you.

You can use a *method* call to find out if a `username` has already been used and warn the new user in the UI before they create their account.

client:

```
Meteor.call('usernameExists', username, function(err, result){
  if (result) {
    alert('Username '+username+' is already taken!')
    // clear out the form etc...
  }
});
```

server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  usernameExists(username){
    return Meteor.users.findOne({username}) !== 'undefined';
  }
});
```